# In order traversal of a left threaded BST falls into infinty loop

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a left threaded BST and I want to traverse inorder and print some data of each node in a line. I use the below method but it stucks between first and second shown node . let's see the code:

```
void InOrder(thnode *root) {
thnode *p = root;
if (p->left)
    InOrder(p->left);
cout << p->info << ",";
if (p->left) cout << p->left->info << ",";
else cout << "null,";
if (p->lthread)cout << "T" << endl;
else cout << "F" << endl;
if (p->right)
    InOrder(p->right);
}
```

output :

```
-1,null,T  
0,-1,F  
-1,null,T  
0,-1,F  
.  
.  
.
```

this is a program in which gets a string and add nodes one after the other and from left to right from the string.Sample input :
`8,3,5,2,9,0,-1,12,1,7,23,14`
the main methods analyses input and adds nodes by using below method :

```
void MakeThreadedBST(int x) {
thnode *p, *q;
p = new thnode;
p->info = x;
p->left = p->right = NULL;
p->lthread = true;
if (Root == NULL) Root = p;
else {
    q = Root;
    while (1) {
        if (p->info < q->info) {
            if (q->lthread) {
                p->left = q->left;
                q->left = p;
                q->lthread = false;
                break;
            } else
                q = q->left;
        } else {
            if (!q->right) {
                q->right = p;
                p->left = q;
                break;
            } else
                q = q->right;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and after adding all nodes I call `InOrder` Method but it just prints two first nodes in inorder traversal of the tree as I mentioned before.

Comment: Please provice a [mcve].

Comment: which part of code / explanation should I add ?

Comment: The part that makes it a mcve ;] if you follow the link, you will find a explanaition of what a mcve is. In a nutshell: It is the minimum amount of code to reproduce the error.

Comment: From your output, it looks like it looks like `root->right->left` is `root`. That's not a tree, it's a cyclic graph. Plus, `root->left` is null, but `root->lthread` is non-null, so the threading is probably broken too (although this may be in some way an accurate threading of a broken tree…). So, your bug is likely to be in the code that creates the tree—code that you haven't shown us, so we can't debug it.

Comment: @abarnert I actually completed my explanation ;)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code:

```
            q->right = p;
            p->left = q;
```

Whenever you place a node `p` as the right child of an existing node `q`, you set `p->left` to point at its parent, `q`, rather than its left subtree (which is just null). So you end up with a cycle: go right from `q` and you reach `p`, then go left from `p` and you reach `q` again. So your tree isn’t a tree, and when you try to walk it as if it were, you end up stuck walking around that cycle forever.

This may not be the only bug in your code, of course, but it’s the bug that’s causing the error you’re asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the Inorder traversal method by editing `if(p->left)` to `if (!p->lthread)` and it fixed successfully :)

```
void InOrder(thnode *root) {
thnode *p = root;
if (!p->lthread)
    InOrder(p->left);
cout << p->info << ",";
if (p->left) cout << p->left->info << ",";
else cout << "null,";
if (p->lthread)cout << "T" << endl;
else cout << "F" << endl;
if (p->right)
    InOrder(p->right);
}
```